# How to insert CookieCollection to CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

After I get response from httpwebrequest, I'd like the cookies obtained to save for the purpose of using them in another httbwebrequest. However, I'd need to insert CookieCollection to CookieContainer. How do I do that? Tried to do:

```
request.Cookiecontainer.add(response.Cookies);
```

but this keeps getting out of error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

According to Microsoft:

> CookieContainer is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) by default. You must assign a CookieContainer object to the property to have cookies returned in the Cookies property of the HttpWebResponse returned by the GetResponse method.

Answer (score 2):

```
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. -> I'm asking because this error keeps popping out on THIS code line..

Comment: Just instantiate a CookieContainer before you add the cookies

Answer (score 0):

```
dim cookie as new cookiecontainer

//request codes here
//response here

cookie.add(response.cookies)
```